# Is there a simple way to reorder lists of different sizes for interation?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

basically I want to recorder a list that is 2-4 numbers based on the order of a list that is longer. Neither are ordered by value. for example:

I want to sort the list [4,8,5] by the order of [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9, 7]. 
I am trying to get this to iterate though a loop so I can extract values from the shorter list in the order of the longer one over multiple data sets.

---

I have tried zipping the lists, it just gives me the first vales of the longer list eg for this [5,4,2]
the sources for both lists are dataframes, the longer is a sorted list of dataframe indexes. I will be modifying at in order as to not have duplicate changes.

Comment: HI, can you post a sample source code of what have you tried so far? This helps other users to understand more clearly your issue and how to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
>>> items = [4,8,5]
>>> order = [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9, 7]
>>> items.sort(key = lambda item : order.index(item))
>>> items
[5, 4, 8]
```

Comment: The sorting order is determined by the position of the item within the order array. `5` is at index 0. `4` is at position 1 and `8` is at 6.